# Build with Hibernate is not working (only Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, build, netbeans-8

I created an application in Java with JavaFx and Hibernate.
in my IDE is working everything correct. but when I build the application and launch the .jar file all the functions that use Hibernate doesn´t work.

I create another testapp to show you my code:

here is my main class:

```
package testapp;

import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Testapp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ComboBox<Test> cmbtest=new ComboBox<>();
        ObservableList<Test> l=FXCollections.observableArrayList(loadCmb());     
        StackPane root = new StackPane();      
        root.getChildren().add(cmbtest);
        cmbtest.setItems(l);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public List<Test> loadCmb(){
        List<Test> list;
        SessionFactory sf;
        sf= NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();       
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Query query=session.createQuery("FROM Test test");        
        list=query.list();
        return list;   
        }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <mapping resource="testapp/Test.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is my NewHibernateUtil:

```
package testapp;

import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sf;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistrry;    

    static {
        try {   
             File file=new File("src/testapp/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure(file);            
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb= new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
            StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry= sb.build();
            sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {            
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sf;
    }
}
```

this is my only class, created from my database in MySql

```
package testapp;
// Generated 24/10/2016 01:53:10 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1



/**
 * Test generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Test  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private String name;
     private Integer number;

    public Test() {
    }


    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Test(String name, Integer number) {
       this.name = name;
       this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

mySql is one table with 2 columns
testTable:
Name and number

if I run this program in my IDE the application is running correctly, but when I build the application, the .jar file is not working.

here is the output from my build:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Dani-Fla-Mathi\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\testapp jfx-rebuild
init:
deps-clean:
Created dir: \testapp\build
Updating property file: \testapp\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory \testapp\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: \testapp\build
Updating property file: \testapp\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: \testapp\build\classes
Created dir: \testapp\build\empty
Created dir: \testapp\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to \testapp\build\classes
Note:\testapp\src\testapp\Testapp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 3 files to \testapp\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: \testapp\dist
Copying 17 files to \testapp\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
jfx-rebuild:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

please let me know if you need further information

Comment: Sorry about this
build*
using*

Comment: How can somebody recommend what you are missing without any code, any error messages?

Comment: Considerably more information is required for anyone to be able to answer this question (without just making guesses as to any of the large number of things that could be wrong). Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to frame your question according to the guidelines there.

Comment: I assume he does not create a proper classpath and just runs the jar of the javafx application. There are multiple options. Reading the following is most likely a good idea https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: @DimaSan this is the problem. I don´t receive any error in the application.
for Example. I have a button to open a scene. in this scene I have a comboBox that is populated with some information from my DB.
when I click on this button the scene is not opening

Comment: @DanielNacher It is highly unlikely you don't get any error unless you are suppressing the exceptions in your code. You should create the smallest possible application that illustrates the same problem: probably all you need is a simple start method that retrieves a list of objects via a very simple query and puts the objects in a listview, or something similar. Make sure it runs from your IDE, bundle it as a jar, and run the jar from the command line. [Edit] your question to include the code and the stack trace, if there is one. Voting to close until the question is edited.

Comment: this is the output of clean and build operation:

ant -f ***** jfx-rebuild
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: ****\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory ****\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: *****\build
Updating property file: ****\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: ******build\classes
Created dir: ******\build\empty
Created dir: ******\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 52 source files to*******\build\classes

Comment: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 51 files to *******\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: ******\dist
Copying 47 files to *******\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.

Comment: Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
jfx-rebuild:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: @DanielNacher Those last comments are unreadable. [Edit] your question to include the additional information, along with the information requested.

Comment: @James_D thank you. sorry about the lack of information. I´m starting in this world.
i will try to do what you suggested and I will come back

Comment: @James_D now is edited. hope that this information is useful

Comment: You should be seeing an exception when you try to execute a jar file version of that. If you run from the command line (i.e. `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`), do you see a stack trace?

Comment: (Oh, BTW, thanks for providing a [MCVE]. This is exactly how you should ask a question like this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the hibernate configuration from a file, whose path is specified relative to the current working directory:

```
File file=new File("src/testapp/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure(file);
```

Clearly, when you deploy the application as a jar file, this file path will no longer make sense (apart from anything else, the `src` folder will not be included in the jar file, and will not be otherwise available at runtime).

You should instead specify the configuration file as a resource, giving the URL:

```
URL resource = NewHibernateUtil.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure(resource);
```

Assuming everything else is being deployed correctly, i.e. the config file is deployed to the jar file, the hibernate jars are on the classpath, etc, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. that was the error. now is working correclty.

Comment: @DanielNacher You're welcome. Please mark the answer as correct: it will help others find it if they have a similar problem.